# Protocol Extension default variable implementation throws segmentation fault 11

Tags: swift

I want to create protocol extension with default implementation of variables. This simple code throws segmentation fault 11, it crashes in playground as well.
It works fine when "set" keyword is deleted, but then I can't simply set values to "test" variable in classes implementing this protocol
Any tips?

```
import UIKit

protocol Prot {
    var test: Int { get set }
}

extension Prot {
    var test: Int {
        return 1
    }
}

struct TestStruct: Prot {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a segmentation fault, then it's surely a Swift compiler bug.
Even if that worked though, this code still shouldn't compile.

The reason is that your extension defines a default `get` for `test`, but `TestStruct` doesn't have a `set` for it, so it doesn't conform to `Prot` yet.
If that bug wasn't there, you would've received an error message along the lines of `TestStruct doesn't conform to protocol Prot`

p.s.: think of sending a bug to bugs.swift.org as it is a quite minimal example and it would be appreciated

Comment: Thanks, it works now with adding `set`. I'm gonna submit this bug to Swift project